# Reading JSON sent by PHP in an extjs file 

Tags: json, extjs

I'm new to extjs and I have a problem. I send JSON from PHP using `echo`. When I send static HTML it's ok, but when I send an encoded JSON string I have a result like this shown:

```
{account:blablabla, amount:blablabla}
```

What can I do?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Show some code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're having problems because you haven't included the property values in single quotes.  blablabla will likely blow up your JavaScript engine.  Or are you trying to figure out how to get JavaScript to actually interpret the JSON object?  Use eval, also, read the ExtJs documentation, they have examples.

Comment: no it is all right with syntax, i forgot to write qoutes here